# Building asp.net core in Teamcity failing with dependencies

Tags: asp.net-core, devops

I am new to the DevOPs field. I am trying to build a .netcore project using teamcity which is failing with dependencies errors.                                               The dependency System.Diagnostics.Contracts >= 4.0.1 could not be resolved.                  The dependency System.Net.WebSockets >= 4.0.0 could not be resolved.                          The dependency System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives >= 4.1.1                          The dependency System.Text.Encodings.Web >= 4.0.0 could not be resolved.              I talked to one of the colleagues and he suggested to install the nugget packages but the solution is building on my and the devs system but is failing by Teamcity. how can I install the dependencies on teamcity.                                      In Asp.net the nugget package management is done automatically(some one told me) So how to do it in .netcore.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40922244/dotnet-core-deployment-to-azure-app-service-using-teamcity

Answer (score 0):

found out that the terminology is called package restore and in dotnet core it is done by running

dotnet restore

from the directory where the project.json is located or the directory can be passed an an argument as well. After the restore there is no need to run msbuild. build can be done using 
dotnet build

The new problem that I am facing now is that after the build and publishing the output folder to Azure web app I am unable to run my dot net core project as to run the project I need to run the command 
dotnet nameoftheproject.dll 
but I dont know how to run this command using teamcity after publish.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40922244/dotnet-core-deployment-to-azure-app-service-using-teamcity